# PHP - how to get image from numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, image

I have two pages cloth.php and second one is pickup.php

On cloth.php i can select multiple product (coming from DB) using checkbox which has image, price and title and after submit it redirect to pickup.php page with holding product details.

So i am getting an array (combination of text and images) on pickup.php
i can get using values using

```
foreach ($dada as $value) {
     echo "<h1>$value<br></h1>";
}
```

i am getting demo product (product name), 455 (product price), image.jpg (product image).
I am getting image name here but i want to display image, how can i do this ?

NOTE : number of rows in array vary every time based on selection of products.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the Image name from $_FILES array and Put it in your <img src tag, with the path.

Comment: Array ( 
          [0] => Front with Hooks1.png 
          [1] => 8 
          [2] => Back with Hooks
          [3] => bls 2.png
          [4] => Dart/Regular Blouse 
          [5] => 0 
          [6] => 5 Days deli.jpg
          [7] => Delivery in 5 days 
          [8] => 100 
          [9] => Task-106-Add-Ons1.jpg 
         [10] => Premium Cotton Lining
         [11] => 150 )

Comment: Please tell me how can i achieve this from this array ?

Comment: Have you stored the images in Server? So that we can give path to it and show?

Comment: Image name is stored in DB and image is saved in a folder

Answer (score 0):

Filter your master Array of Images and put it in to one array and get the path from server and display it using img tag

```
$DisplayImages[0] =  "Front with Hooks1.png";
$DisplayImages[1] =  8;
$DisplayImages[2] =  "Back with Hooks";
$DisplayImages[3] =  "bls 2.png";
$DisplayImages[4] =  "Dart/Regular Blouse";
$DisplayImages[5] =  0;
$DisplayImages[6] =  "5 Days deli.jpg";
$DisplayImages[7] =  "Delivery in 5 days";
$DisplayImages[8] =  100;
$DisplayImages[9] =  "Task-106-Add-Ons1.jpg";
$DisplayImages[10] =  "Premium Cotton Lining";
$DisplayImages[11] =  150;

$supported_image = array(
'gif',
'jpg',
'jpeg',
'png'
);

echo ('<!DOCTYPE html>');
echo ('<html>');
echo ('<head>');
echo ('<title></title>');
echo ('</head>');
echo ('<body>');

 foreach ($DisplayImages as $key => $value) 
 {
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Using strtolower to overcome case sensitive
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_image)) 
    {
    //Give your server path of image here and  Display it.
        $ImgPath = "../I/Profiles".$value;  // In this case I have image in my I folder profiles
        echo ( '<img src='.$ImgPath.' alt="Image" height="42" width="42">');   
    } 
    else
    {
        echo $value;  // Not an Image
    }
}


echo ('</body>');
echo ('</html>');
// echo "<pre>";print_r($ImagePath);
// exit();
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your efforts, code looks nice but the issue is -> in array i have both text and image not only images.
And i want show result in proper way means , first product name after image and in last price

Comment: sir even is it possible or not ?
otherwise i will change my concept of getting data on other page.